# Mapping JSON into a custom object which contains map

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I have a json like this, which is nested for one of the fields -

```
{
    "templateid": "email_verified_template",
    "templatevalues": {
        "patient_name": "nprj09”,
        "date": “Monday, 3rd May, 10:37:23 PM”,
    },
    "emailAddress": “nprj09@test.com”,
}
```

I've created a custom class,

```
public class EmailTemplate implements Serializable {

    private String templateid;
    private Map<String,String> templatevalues;
    private String emailAddress;

    ---
}
```

In my service class, I'm reading the json and mapping it into my EmailTemplate class, but mapping fails. What can I use here?

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
   notificationVo = mapper.readValue(msg, EmailNotificationVO.class);
```

Exception:

```
An Exception has occurred..com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value
 at [Source: (String)"{
    "templateid": "email_verified_template",
    "templatevalues": {
        "patient_name": "nprj09”,
        "date": “Monday, 3rd May, 10:37:23 PM”
```

I tried adding

```
mapper.configure(
                    JsonReadFeature.ALLOW_UNESCAPED_CONTROL_CHARS.mappedFeature(),
                    true
            );
```

But that did not work either.

Comment: The JSON is invalid

Comment: Look at the quotes

Comment: Right, thanks. Missed the basic thing.

Answer (score 0):

The code to map is fine. Just correct input JSON.

Answer (score 0):

First, as pointed out by [Most Needed Rabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13312820/most-needed-rabbit), the quotes in the JSON are incorrect. Correcting that, here is the code that works.

Input String:

```
String input = "{\n" +
                "\t\"templateid\": \"email_verified_template\",\n" +
                "\t\"templatevalues\": {\n" +
                "\t\t\"patient_name\": \"nprj09\",\n" +
                "\t\t\"date\": \"Monday, 3 rd May, 10: 37: 23 PM\"\n" +
                "\t},\n" +
                "\t\"emailAddress\": \"nprj09@test.com\"\n" +
                "}";
```

The code to read the JSON:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            EmailTemplate email = mapper.readValue(input, EmailTemplate.class);
            System.out.println(email.getTemplatevalues().get("patient_name"));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Simple POJO with getters and setters:

```
class EmailTemplate implements Serializable {
    private String templateid;
    private Map<String,String> templatevalues;
    private String emailAddress;

    public String getTemplateid() {
        return templateid;
    }

    public void setTemplateid(String templateid) {
        this.templateid = templateid;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getTemplatevalues() {
        return templatevalues;
    }

    public void setTemplatevalues(Map<String, String> templatevalues) {
        this.templatevalues = templatevalues;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }
}
```

It prints the `patient_name` by marshalling it into the POJO and reading it from inside the Object.